# Не выводится форма contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form7

Почему не выводится форма

создал поля с помощью Carbon Fields, внедрил в шаблон fancybox 3,

и при всплывании окна  выводится код формы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

хотя в странице форма выводится,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**что делаю не так**?

Comment: Не срабатывет шорткод. Тот компонент, что выводит форму во всплывающем окне, не делает `do_shortcode()`

Comment: спасибо за подсказку помогло, пришлось в шаблоне прописать                <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="70" title="Контактная форма 1"]'); ?>                                                                                                     хотя там есть возможность добавить Rich Text (визуальный редактор) но все равно выводится только код формы